# Функция, работающая с каждым элементом одного массива и записывающая в другой

Tags: python

Дана функция `sin(2*3.14*a/50)/cos(2*3.14*a/50)`. Нужно определить функцию, которая берет каждый элемент, скажем, списка `a` и записывает в соотв. элементы списка `y`. Затем заполнить `a` и с помощью функции переписать в `y`.
Код на C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void tangens (int *a, float *y)
{
    *y = sin(2*3.14*(*a)/50)/cos(2*3.14*(*a)/50);
}

main()
{
int i;
int a[50];
float b[50];
for(i=0; i < 50; i++)
{
    tangens(&(a[i]), &(b[i]));
    printf("%f, ", b[i]);
}
}
```

Вроде так, а вот аналогично на python... Как ни пытаюсь, разобраться не выходит. Именно определение функции со списками в кач-ве аргумента. Ковырялся внутри, объявлял пустую + внутри добавлял функ. `append()` - все ни по чем. как бы вы эту самую функцию определили?

Comment: Условия не ясны: что у вас на входе в Питоне (просто функция для *скалярного* аргумента, которую вы хотите затабулировать в диапазоне `[0, 2*pi)`, используя данное кол-во точек)? Если вы хотите существующий список `y` изменить, то только значения должны быть изменены или длина также, если она отличается от `a`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def some_function(x):
    return x * x

def f1(a):
    return [some_function(x) for x in a]
    # return map(some_function, a)

def f2(a, b):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        b[i] = some_function(a[i])

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [0, 0, 0]

f2(a, b)
print b

print f1(a)
```

закомментированная строка в f1 эквивалентна разкомментированной.

Кстати, в Вашем примере на С, функция tangens вовсе не работает с массивами, если вы уж вызываете ее в цикле. Функция работающая с массивами выглядит, например, так:

```
void tangens(int *a, float *y, int num_of_items) {
    fot (int i=0; i<num_of_items; i++) {
        *(y++) = sin(pi * (*a)) / cos(pi * (*a));
        a++;
    }
}
```

или так:

```
void tangens(int *a, float *y, int num_of_items) {
    fot (int i=0; i<num_of_items; i++) {
        y[i] = sin(pi * a[i]) / cos(pi * a[i]);
    }
}
```